# 2004 PT Cruiser Overheating

Tags: overheating

My '04 PT Cruiser has started overheating. I ran the heater as told and it just overheated really bad one day.  Now my car doesn't turn on. I turn the key and it drags bad, but doesn't start.

What should I do?

Comment: `it overheated really bad`...  That is not a good thing. If it overheats badly you should stop before it warps the engine block. If it already did that than you indeed have a problem.

Comment: How bad did it overheat? How high did the temperature gauge go and for how long?

Answer (score 2):

### Before you invest another penny on this vehicle

Have a mechanic run a compression test on all engine cylinders and compare those values against the car's engine specifications.

This should prevent anyone from second-guessing the cause of the no-start condition. There is little value in throwing expensive fixes on a vehicle without evidence, and the compression test should arm you with data.

If the numbers come back ok, there is no reason to believe the new-engine/cylinder-head/head-gasket song-and-dance will solve the issue. You can then focus on other systems to understand what is going on.